# Rubu on Rails print only field forms with values

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have 
`form_for @shop,:url => {:action => :withdraw_from} do |f|`
that outputs a form with many fields like this:

```
<div class="field inventory">
  <label for="5cent">5cent</label>
  <input type="text" name="5cent" id="5cent" placeholder="5">
</div>
```

When the submit button is pressed I want to print to a printer only the fields of a form that the user fills . I am thinking of making a check with javascript before printing but I dont know if it's the right way.
Would it be right to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form_submit").click(function(event) {
      if (!validate_inventory()){
        alert('Check the drawer!');
      }else{
          ADD ONLY FIELDS WITH INPUT TO THE PRINT INTERFACE 
          window.print();
          $('#withdraw_form').submit();
      }
    });
});
```

How can I get only fields with input?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to mark input fields on change:

```
$("input").on("change", e => {
  e.target.data("changed", true) // or similar
})
```

and next iterate of those on submit:

```
$("#form_submit").click(function(event) {
   $('*[data-changed="true"]').each( changed => doSomethingWithMe(changed) )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the values of a form by creating a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance.

```js
$("#form_submit").click(function(event) {
  let formData = new FormData(event.target.form);
  let obj = {}
  formData.forEach(function(value, key){
    if (value && value !== "") {
      obj[key] = value;
    }
  });
  console.log(obj);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="foo">Foo</label>
  <input type="text" name="5cent" value="John Doe" />
  <input type="text" name="a" />
  <input type="text" name="b" />
  <select name="c"> 
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="print" id="form_submit">
</form>
```